# Angular where to add child element in parent

Tags: angular, typescript

My goal is to call a method from another component, I am using @Output EventEmitter

My Scenario looks like:

```
 <p-button(onClick)="delete()">
```

**componentAChild.component.ts:**

```
@Output() refreshValue = new EventEmitter();

delete(){
//delete code
this.onDeleteUpdateValue();
}

onDeleteUpdateValue(){
this.refreshValue.emit();
}
```

---

**componentBParent.component.ts:**

```
onEventRefreshValue(){
 this.refresh();
}

refresh(){
//do something
}
```

**componentBParent.component.html**

I don't know where I should include the child component inside the parent template.

Child component:

```
<app-componentA(refreshValue)="onEventRefreshValue()"></app-componentA>
```

My parent template, includes Pagination/Lazy loading, something like the primeNG table:

```
<div>
    <p-table [value]="customers" [lazy]="true" (onLazyLoad)="loadCustomers($event)"
        [paginator]="true" [rows]="10" [totalRecords]="totalRecords" [loading]="loading" [globalFilterFields]="['name','country.name', 'company', 'representative.name']">
        <ng-template pTemplate="header">
            <tr>
                <th pSortableColumn="name">Name <p-sortIcon field="name"></p-sortIcon></th>
                <th pSortableColumn="country.name">Country <p-sortIcon field="country.name"></p-sortIcon></th>
                <th pSortableColumn="company">Company <p-sortIcon field="company"></p-sortIcon></th>
                <th pSortableColumn="representative.name">Representative <p-sortIcon field="representative.name"></p-sortIcon></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <p-columnFilter type="text" field="name"></p-columnFilter>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <p-columnFilter type="text" field="country.name"></p-columnFilter>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <p-columnFilter type="text" field="company"></p-columnFilter>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <p-columnFilter field="representative" matchMode="in" [showMenu]="false">
                        <ng-template pTemplate="filter" let-value let-filter="filterCallback">
                            <p-multiSelect [ngModel]="value" [options]="representatives" placeholder="Any" (onChange)="filter($event.value)" optionLabel="name">
                                <ng-template let-option pTemplate="item">
                                    <div class="p-multiselect-representative-option">
                                        <img [alt]="option.label" src="assets/showcase/images/demo/avatar/{{option.image}}" width="32" style="vertical-align: middle" />
                                        <span class="p-ml-1">{{option.name}}</span>
                                    </div>
                                </ng-template>
                            </p-multiSelect>
                        </ng-template>
                    </p-columnFilter>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-customer>
            <tr>
                <td>{{customer.name}}</td>
                <td>{{customer.country.name}}</td>
                <td>{{customer.company}}</td>
                <td>{{customer.representative.name}}</td>
            </tr>
        </ng-template>
    </p-table>
</div>
```

Any suggestions, as well could you help me to find the right documentation in Angular to find out more about it

Comment: Actually I don't need to send any data. I tried to include the child component just after the <div> tag in the parent, but when I start the application, it doesn't display anything. Where is a right place to add the child inside the parent?

Comment: Well, whereever you want it to be in your layout. Placing it after the `</div>` in parent would be just fine (if it is a per row button for deleting the row, you'd put it in a column cell). If it doesn't show up: do you get any errors in the console while serving? Sounds to me like there is something wrong.

Comment: so far I have no errors, but nothing is displayed, do I need to add a condition into the child component to "activate it" until the event is sent?

Comment: No. You can check the dom to see if the button is actually there. Had a look at your button again and you don't specify a label. Maybe that is why it's not showing.

Answer (score 0):

you can work with events like this:

child component:

```js
@Output() refreshValue: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

delete() {
    this.refreshValue.emit({ data: 'your data' });
}
```

```html
 <p-button(onClick)="delete()">
```

and in your parent component you should listen to the emitted event like this:

```js
remove() {
    let yourData = 'the thing you desire to do';
}
```

```html
 <app-your-component
        (delete)="removeItem()"
></app-your-component>
```